# create live wallpaper in viewpager android apps

Tags: android, android-viewpager, live-wallpaper

Hi i have a app contain 3 page. and i want to set one page as background like android home screen. I search in google and i found [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-renderscript-on-android--mobile-9154) and [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android--mobile-9516)
         tutorial's but i couldn't use it for my target can anyone show me another better example thanks.

i mean How can i create app like android home screen which have one picture for 5 pages background (in my phone).

Comment: Unclear question. You want a fixed background for a `ViewPager`?

Comment: i want something like android home page but in my app like camera360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i found my answer and that was so simpler that i think.
that was not a live wallpaper that was simple trick using scroolview  for background of main layout and listen to onPageScrollStateChanged.
that's it.